# Which CODE is used to print thread name in PS?

Tags: linux

```
$ ps -mo pid,spid,tid,%cpu,psr,ucmd -p 4444     // first command
  PID  SPID   TID %CPU PSR CMD
 4444     -     -  1.4   - main-app
    -  4444  4444  1.1   0 -
    -  8675  8675  0.1   0 -
    -  8676  8676  0.1   0 -

$ ps -T -p 4444
  PID  SPID TTY          TIME CMD
 4444  4444 ?        00:16:50 main-app
 4444  8675 ?        00:02:44 thread-one
 4444  8676 ?        00:02:38 thread-two
```

Question> The `-T` switch generates a CMD column that indicates the name for each thread within the same process(i.e. main-app). Which CODE I should use to print out the same CMD column in the first command? I have tried `ucmd` and `cmd` but none of them show the expected thread name.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `m` with `T`.

```
ps -To pid,spid,tid,%cpu,psr,ucmd -p 4444
```